# c++ App on arrays using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Question: How do I generate a random animal from the array using that function?

```
const int MAX =12;       //12 animals

const int MAXSTR = 10;   //Max length for set

typedef char * Element;
static Element UniversalSet [MAX] = {"Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon","Snake", "Sheep", "Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig", "Horse"};

void constructSet (Element *, int size)
{   
    Element* s;

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) 
    {
         s[i] = UniversalSet [rand() % 12];
    }
        cout << "Set S = {" << s[i] << "}";

}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: name lookup of 'i' changed for new ISO 'for' scoping

Comment: using obsolete binding at 'i'

Comment: Those are the 2 errors, thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error move the `cout` inside the loop :

```
  void constructSet(Element * elements, int size)
{
    Element* s = elements;

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        s[i] = UniversalSet[rand() % 12];

        cout << "Set S = {" << s[i] << "}";//Here
    }

}
```

then try this and it will work :

```
Element e[3] ;
constructSet(e, 3);
```